# How can a f-curve be used in an animation in BGE?

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks, audio

I created some f-curves for different frequencies from an MP3 files, using the "*bake sound from f-curve*" function from the *Key* menu in the *f-curves editor*. The curves are assigned to a keyframe and scale the cubes while the music plays the MP3 has been added as a sound strip in VSE (looks like spectrum analyzer).

How could the f-curves be used in the BGE, could they possibly assigned to an action?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F-curve is generally used for controlling actions, I assume that you were asking "how to use action in BGE".

The simplest way is to set the **Actuator** type to **Action**. Then choose the action you want, and tweak a few settings within it, as shown below. Hope I didn't misunderstand that.

[image]

---

**EDIT**: I'm feeling that I sort of misunderstood that, did I? :-\

Comment: Thanks, my bad, I didn't notice that Blender had already created the required actions. Your answer made me setup the logik bricks and the actions where already available there!